# Installing Wordpress on multiple sub-domains

Tags: wordpress

I have 50 subdomains (created in cpanel) and want to install wordpress on each one - I do do it manually using Softaculous, but can it be done automatically? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No, There is no other way. You can use **Softaculous** or you can upload the latest WordPress on your server.
>   **Softaculous** is an easier way that creates a database it self for your WordPress installation.